# MySQL Stored Procedure Error Unexpected character ":"

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have the following statement to create a stored procedure, but I keep getting an "Unexpected character ':' at position 835" error.  The only colon in the statement is in the start_loop: loop.  Why am I getting this error and how can I fix?

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_gauge_values` (in maxdate timestamp, in tagid int)

BEGIN   
    declare finished boolean;
    declare line_timestamp timestamp;
    declare line_tagid int;
    declare line_name varchar(50);
    declare line_value varchar(50);

    -- CREATE OUR TEMP TABLE
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS GAUGE_VALUES_TEMP;
    CREATE TABLE GAUGE_VALUES_TEMP (
        LINE_NAME varchar(255),
        LINE_VALUE varchar(50)
    );

    -- CREATE OUR CURSOR
    DECLARE cid CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT MAX(hd.timestamp), hd.tag_id
        FROM dashboard_lines dl
        JOIN historical_data hd ON hd.tag_id = dl.gauge_tag_id
        WHERE (hd.timestamp is null OR hd.timestamp <= maxdate)
        AND (dl.gauge_tag_id is null OR dl.gauge_tag_id = tagid);       

    set finished=false;
    declare continue handler for not found set finished=true;

    open cid;

    start_loop: loop        

        fetch cid into line_timestamp, line_tagid;    

        if finished <> false then 
            leave start_loop;
        else
            insert into gauge_values_temp (line_name, line_value)
            select ol.name, hd.value
            from dashboard_lines dl
            join operation_lines ol on ol.line_id = dl.line_id
            join historical_data hd on hd.tag_id = dl.gauge_tag_id
            where dl.gauge_tag_id = line_tagid;            
        end if;        

    end loop;

    close cid;

    select * from gauge_values_temp;

END
$$
```

Comment: I'm not sure here but, everywhere I saw this statement it uses case sensitive for the loop word. So, try changing `start_loop: loop` to `start_loop: LOOP` and `end loop;` to `END LOOP;`. As I said, not sure though.

Comment: @JorgeCampos thank you for the suggestion.  It ended up being a TAB character.  See accepted answer.  Thanks again!!!

Comment: [Why not to use `while` statement?](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/while.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a very annoying MySQL syntax related issue: There is a TAB somewhere in you procedure leading to this parse issue: Use spaces only for any indentation or alignment.

My version (MariaDB 10.x) also does not like the start of your procedure with the `DECLARE` order, so I also updated that. See if it still fits your purpose at that location.

The adjusted procedure which my database creates without syntax errors:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_gauge_values` (in maxdate timestamp, in tagid int)

BEGIN
declare finished boolean;
declare line_timestamp timestamp;
declare line_tagid int;
declare line_name varchar(50);
declare line_value varchar(50);
DECLARE cid CURSOR FOR 
SELECT MAX(hd.timestamp), hd.tag_id
FROM dashboard_lines dl
JOIN historical_data hd ON hd.tag_id = dl.gauge_tag_id
WHERE (hd.timestamp is null OR hd.timestamp <= maxdate)
AND (dl.gauge_tag_id is null OR dl.gauge_tag_id = tagid);       
declare continue handler for not found set finished=true;
set finished=false;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS GAUGE_VALUES_TEMP;
CREATE TABLE GAUGE_VALUES_TEMP (
LINE_NAME varchar(255),
LINE_VALUE varchar(50)
);  
open cid;
start_loop: loop            
fetch cid into line_timestamp, line_tagid;    
if finished <> false then 
leave start_loop; 
else    
insert into gauge_values_temp (line_name, line_value) 
select ol.name, hd.value
from dashboard_lines dl
join operation_lines ol on ol.line_id = dl.line_id
join historical_data hd on hd.tag_id = dl.gauge_tag_id
where dl.gauge_tag_id = line_tagid;                        
end if;                
end loop;
close cid;
select * from gauge_values_temp;
END
$$
```

Comment: Costed me a few days once... I think nobody expects that one.